# Is xsl copy broken with respect to xpath axes?

Tags: xslt, copy

The xsl copy function appears to deviate from the functional hierarchical pattern of the copy-of in that it doesn't assess the select condition (if condition is an XPath axes) before applying the function action.

so `xsl:copy select="ancestor::*"` will behave different than `xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*"`

Comment: Could you provide an example ? Hint: I am quite sure xsl:copy is not broken.

Comment: Hey Driis, we can use any data xml (3 levels+). If your current node is 1 of the leave nodes, the xsl:copy with parent:: gives me the current node while xsl:copy-of select="parent::*" gives me the parent's node (fluff: & of course the descendants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `copy` and `copy-of` are intended to do very different things. `copy` always works on the *current node* and does not support the `select` attribute. See http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_copy.html vs http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_copy-of.html.

Answer (score 4):

At least in XSLT 1.0, `xsl:copy` does **not** have a select attribute: it only copies the current node.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) (emphasis mine):

> The xsl:copy element provides an easy way of copying **the current node**. Instantiating the xsl:copy element creates a copy of the current node. The namespace nodes of the current node are automatically copied as well, but the attributes and children of the node are not automatically copied. The content of the xsl:copy element is a template for the attributes and children of the created node; the content is instantiated only for nodes of types that can have attributes or children (i.e. root nodes and element nodes).

*Edit: XSLT2.0 [`xsl:copy`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-copy) behaves the same way*

Answer (score 0):

A select attribute is being added to xsl:copy in XSLT 3.0, to allow copying of nodes other than the context node (useful for example in a function). For XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, I really don't know what you mean.